# Rails: Search on select_tag

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

What i want is to load the results on my index as son as an option form the `select` is selected. I have successfully done this, however, i am not sure this is the right way.

VIEW:

Here, `text` and `text_value` are functions defined in model, please avoid them.

Below is my code. I'm sorry if this is not in its best manner.

```
$(function(){
  $("#email_template").change(function(){
    var v = $("#email_template option:selected").data('t');
    if (v == "DefaultEmailTemplate")
    {
      var id = $("#email_template option:selected").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/email_templates?email_template=" + id,
        success: function(data){
          location.href = "/email_templates?email_template=" + id
        }

      });
    }
    else if(v == "AutomationSeries") {
      var id = $("#email_template").val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/email_templates?automation_series=" + id,
        success: function(data){
          location.href = "/email_templates?automation_series=" + id
        }    
      });
    }
    else{
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/email_templates",
        success: function(data){
          location.href = "/email_templates"
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

What my problem here is, that i have to set the `location.href = "/email_templates"` after the ajax success because then i don't get redirected. Also, because of this redirection, i am loosing my selected value and the default prompt option is shown in the `select` instead of the `option` on which the search was performed. And i am also not so sure about providing the `URL` as it doesn't really make a difference.

I'm sorry if i am not clear. I have been scratching my head over this for hours now.

P.S.: Rails and Ajax newbie here.

Comment: You should not be setting `location.href`. What you should be doing is use the `data` that the server gives you back and fill the content in your page.

Comment: i have this in my index page. In my controller i check if the params are set and display the records accordingly. For index to display records accordingly, i want to send the params in url and hence using the location.href cause otherwise, nothing happens on selection. I am sorry if the code seems wrong but this is what i knew so implemented. Please guide me if there is a better solution. Right now everything works perfectly except the part where the selected option should be 'Selected'.